# Distance to the galaxy which has velocity which is perpendicular to the point of view of the static observer

Tags: cosmology, doppler-effect, distance

Let's have the galaxy which has velocity which is perpendicular to the point of view of the static observer in the FLRW universe. It emits the light. There is a given redshift $z_{0}$. It will be easy to find the distance from the galaxy to the observer from the relation for light which moves radially (let the universe be spatially flat):
$$
dt^2 - a^2(t) dr^2 = 0 \Rightarrow r = \int \frac{dt}{a(t)}. \qquad (1)
$$
But then I need to determine the relation between $a(t)$ and $z$. If the galaxy is at rest, this relation is easy: 
$$
\frac{a_{0}}{a(t)} = 1 + z, \quad \frac{\dot {a}}{a_{0}} = H.
$$ 
But in this case I have to take into account the transverse Doppler redshift in a form 
$$
\frac{a_{0}}{a(t)} = (1 + z)\sqrt{1 - v^2(z)}.
$$
So how to get $v(z)$ and how to rewrite integral $(1)$ in terms of variable $z$,
$$
\int \limits_{0}^{t} \to \int \limits_{0}^{z_{0}}?
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cosmological distance to a faraway galaxy only depends on its cosmic redshift $z_\text{cos}$, i.e. the redshift caused by the expansion of the universe; it does not depend on the Doppler redshift $z_\text{dop}$ caused by the galaxy's motion within its local cluster. So we have
$$
\frac{a_0}{a(t)} = 1 + z_\text{cos}.
$$
Now, what we observe is the *total* redshift $z$ of the galaxy, which is a combination of the cosmic redshift and the Doppler redshift:
$$
1 + z = (1 + z_\text{cos})(1 + z_\text{dop}).
$$
Actually, there's also the contribution of another Doppler redshift due to our own motion with respect to the CMB, but let's ignore this (and there are also gravitational redshift effects, but these are even smaller and very hard to derive). So in principle one can derive the galaxy's cosmic redshift from the total observed redshift if one is able to determine $z_\text{dop}$. However, there are a few things that I should point out.

First of all, galaxies move at non-relativistic speeds within their clusters, typically of the order $v \sim 1000\,\text{km/s}$ in large systems, which means that their Doppler redshifts $z_\text{dop}\approx v/c$ are very small. So small in fact that the correction from $z$ to $z_\text{cos}$ doesn't matter that much, especially not for very distant galaxies, where the correction will be much smaller than the uncertainties in the cosmological parameters.

Second, it's impossible to separate the transverse and the line-of-sight Doppler shifts: we cannot observe the direction of the galaxy's motion in its cluster. In other words, if we measure $z_\text{dop}$, then
$$
1 + z_\text{dop} = \frac{1 + v/c \cos\theta}{\sqrt{1 - v^2/c^2}},
$$
but we cannot derive $v$ and $\cos\theta$ separately. However, we can say that for any measurable $z_\text{dop}$, the galaxy has to be moving close to the line of sight ($\theta \approx 0^\circ$ or $\theta \approx 180^\circ$) because otherwise $z_\text{dop}$ would be too small to observe. In other words, the transverse Doppler effect is insignificant.

Third, it is not always possible to determine $z_\text{dop}$. In fact, you can only do this for large clusters of galaxies, for which you can define its cosmic redshift as the average total redshift of its member galaxies:
$$
z_\text{cos} = \frac{1}{N}z_i,
$$
so that for each member galaxy
$$
1 + z_{\text{dop},i} = \frac{1+z_i}{1+z_\text{cos}}.
$$
To summarize: don't worry too much about Doppler redshifts, they have little effect on cosmic distance measurements.